How to insert anchors in html-headers via css
I collect some of my WordPress blog-posts into one html-Doc to publish this via Prince as PDF. 
The problem is the table of contents: It points (via <a href="..."> to docs outside of the html-doc.
Question: is there a way to insert anchors <a id="..."> via CSS into the html-Doc? ( "..." is the title of the <h1> tag)

Can you share what level of customization Prince offers? I'm almost certain you can't achieve this just through CSS.

Please add current HTML codes to the question. Specifically, href values ​​in the Table Of Contents and the id values ​​of the fields they point to.

@Antrikshy: Prince supports parts of level 2-4

@Atakan Au: That are several texts. See the "..." as a variable. The question is: Is it possible to get the texts into CSS and inject an anchor into the  header. Eg.: foo

You can't insert elements into the DOM or change their attributes using only CSS, you'd need JS for that. CSS just controls styles.

@JosephWebber: Thanks! I was afraid of that. So I will write a python script for injection.

as Joseph Webber wrote, the task to get the text ('foo') of <h1>foo</h1> is without JS impossible. To build a table of contents from selected blog-posts of WordPress works with the JS script below. It assumes the following structure:
<div id="pagecontent">
    <ul>
        <li><a ...>1st Title</a></li>
        ... 
        <li><a ...>last Title</a><li> 
    </ul>
    ...
    <h1 ...>1st Title</h1>
    ...
    <h1 ...>last Title</h1>
</div> 
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    linesHTML = document.getElementById("pagecontent").innerHTML; /*get HTML-Text*/
    linesHTML = linesHTML.split('\n'); /*split into lines*/
    for (i=0;i<linesHTML.length;i++) { /* loop over the lines */
        posH = linesHTML[i].indexOf('<h1'); /*get position of <h1> header*/
        posA = linesHTML[i].indexOf('<a');  /*get position of <a> anchor*/
        if (posH > -1){ /*header found?*/
            linkText=getLinkText(linesHTML[i],'h1'); /*get the header text */
            linesHTML[i] = linesHTML[i].substring(0,posH+4) + 'id="' +linkText + '" ' + linesHTML[i].substring(posH+4); /*add the anchor as id with linkText as anchor*/
        } else if (posA > -1) { /*anchor found?*/
            linkText=getLinkText(linesHTML[i],'a'); /*get anchor from TOC*/
            linesHTML[i] = linesHTML[i].substring(0,posA+1) +'a href="#' + linkText + linesHTML[i].substring(linesHTML[i].indexOf('a">')+1); /*replace anchor with linkText*/
        };
    };
    document.getElementById("pagecontent").innerHTML=linesHTML.join('\n'); /*replace the doc with the all the lines*/
};
function getLinkText(line,htmlToken) { /*get the text of header/anchor*/
    linkText=line.substring(line.indexOf(htmlToken+'">')+htmlToken.length+2,line.indexOf('</'+htmlToken+'>'));
    linkText=linkText.replace(/[^A-z^0-9]/g,'-'); /*replace all non alphanum chars by '-'*/
    return linkText;
};
<script>

